# What's the difference between flat color and mixed color?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, assets, fbx

I downloaded a free pack of assets to practice with Unity and when I import it, I read that the FBX files are divided into 2 copies: "flat colors" and "mixed colors". What is the difference or advantages of using one or the other? Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess: `flat` - color is the same for the entire texture. `mixed` - different colors on one texture (e.g. in an image etc) ?

Comment: What is the asset you downloaded? It may help with a correct answer.